# HTTPSendRequest failure: 1753 WinPE

Tags: networking, winpe

I have been creating a WinPE image using the Windows Deployment and Imaging Tools Environment  to run a specific program- however when the image boots up there is no networking capability. The program itself reports a 'HttpSendRequest failure: 1753' when it tries to access the internet. If I go into command prompt and try to ping anything I receive an error that says 'Unable to contact IP driver. General failure.' I have tested the build on multiple computers with the same result, and have tried creating the build on multiple computers and using both the 8.1 and 10 versions of the deployment kit. Let me know if you have any questions, and thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Which winPE based off of which OS? 7,8,10,or etc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to mount the boot.wim, and/or whatever wim files you have and inject the drivers.  I believe you should have a boot.wim and install.wim.  If boot doesn't inject then install.wim.

You need to create c:\networkdrv and populate this folder with the INF and other files from the network drivers.  **EXE and ZIP are no good, they have to be extracted.**

make a directory **c:\mount** and **c:\test**
copy the boot.wim into **test**

DISM.exe /Mount-Wim /WimFile:C:\test\boot.wim /index:1 /MountDir:C:\mount

dism /Image:c:\mount  /Add-Driver /driver:c:\networkdrv /recurse

dism /Unmount-wim /Mountdir:c:\mount /commit

overwrite the boot.wim file with this new one and try again.